# VueJS 3 extract/get reactive() data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have defined reactive obejct:

```
const selectedAnswers = reactive({})
```

Later I assigning values to this object and can see it:

```
Proxy {2: "Lorem, ipsum dolor.", 4: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit axet consectetur adipisicing."}
```

I need to get this object and send it to backend, but can't figure out how to do this.
I can access selectedAnswers[2] it will print "Lorem, ipsum dolor." but keys can change, I tried to get this object with:

```
selectedAnswers.value
selectedAnswers.values
...
```

I can't send it just like "selectedAnswers" I need somehow unwrap data and send it as pure JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`toRaw`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#toraw) on the `reactive` object:

```js
const answers = toRaw(selectedAnswers)
```